# How to use ALL Rows?

Tags: soql

```
SELECT ID FROM Opportunity
```

and it executes.

But If I add "`ALL ROWS`" at the end, i.e.

```
SELECT ID FROM Opportunity ALL ROWS
```

then I got

> "Unknown error parsing query"

Answer (score 13):

You cannot query deleted/archived records from the query editor at this time. A solution without having to go through Data Loader or Workbench is to run the following code as Anonymous Apex.

```
List<Opportunity> allOpps = [SELECT ID FROM Opportunity ALL ROWS];
System.debug(allOpps.size());
```

The debug statement can be modified to suit your needs or continue to work with the retrieved Ids.

Comment: This answer would be improved by an official reference to back up your claim that the developer console does not support this behavior.

Answer (score 8):

I quote the answer provided by @sfdcfox from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008teaIAA

The query editor doesn't use Apex Code-- it executes directly as a REST query API call. There's no way to query deleted records from the developer console's query editor at this point. Use the Apex Data Loader (Export All), or the workbench (workbench.developerforce.com).